# Android Studio SharedPreferences and Font Style

Tags: java, android

I need to fix one problem.

In the Android Studio I am trying to use SharedPreferences and store the font type but there is something wrong with my code. Please help me out.

// Load Text Font start

```
    SharedPreferences myTextFont = this.getSharedPreferences("MyTextFont", MODE_PRIVATE);
    textFont = myTextFont.getInt("font", textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());


    textExample.setTypeface(textExample.getTypeface());
    textView3.setTypeface(textExample.getTypeface(), textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());
```

// Load Text Font end

//Font Buttons start

```
    final Typeface typeface1 = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this,R.font.mkhatvruli);
    type_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textExample.setTypeface(typeface1);


            SharedPreferences myTextFont = getSharedPreferences("MyTextFont", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myTextFont.edit();
            editor.putInt("font", textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());
            editor.commit();



        }
    });
```

When I click, the button font type changes in the text view but does not store.

I think that something is wrong here:
 editor.putInt("font", textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());

Comment: shouldn't `textView3.setTypeface(textExample.getTypeface(), textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());` be `textView3.setTypeface(textExample.getTypeface(), textFont);` ?

Comment: In this line `editor.putInt("font", textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());` change `textExample` to `view` and see what happens. And also cast it to 'TextView` like `TextView t = (TextView) view;`

Comment: what I mean previously is that, you never use `textFont` that you have loaded, at least it not shown on the example above